# Transaction has been pending for long time

Tags: metamask, etherscan

I send funds using [MetaMask](https://metamask.io/). But,maybe I didn't put enough gas.
So it's stuck with other payments that I made after first payment.

Transaction is..

0x1335976d538aa0ca13ba62dd74af884d9d8050bebf331ca2755edaf48798da73

This means that I losed the funds?

Answer (score 1):

Not yet. Due to cryptokitties, the network is too much congested as of now. You seem to have sent 25GWEI for the price which should be good enough. It may sooner get added in the block. Check [here](https://etherscan.io/txsPending) to know the number of transactions pending in the network. You can check your transaction status [here](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x1335976d538aa0ca13ba62dd74af884d9d8050bebf331ca2755edaf48798da73)

Comment: Thank you for answering my questions!I processed it 10 hours ago,However,Is this normally?
I checked  transactions pending in the network and status in Etherscan.
But,I feel that It look like repeat " Pending Confirmation" processing.

Comment: Yeah, it all depends upon the miners. They may want to ignore crytokitties cause they caused the congestion. Don't send another transaction until you see a result to this.

Answer (score 1):

No, in case you transaction was not mined, you didn't loose any funds.  Neither sent by this nor by subsequent transactions.  The reason why subsequent transactions are not mined, is because they use nonces higher than the nonce of the problematic transactions, but transactions has to have no gaps in nonces in order to be mined.  So, if you've sent three transactions **from the same address** with nonces `0`, `1`, and `2`, and transaction with nonce `1` wasn't mined for some reason, then transaction with nonce `2` will not be mined as well.  In order to resolve such situation, you will need to publish another transaction with nonce `1` **from the same address**, and once it will be mined, subsequent transaction will be unblocked.